# Lightroom: How to add superordinated keywords quickly?

Tags: software, tagging, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using LR 5.7 with a keyword hierarchy and have to tag thousands of photos quickly. Using the Shift and Cmd/Ctrl keys helps me assigning a keyword to a bunch of files at once. Sadly if I tick a keyword in the keyword list, then it only applies this single keyword, but not all the superordinated keywords in the hierarchy. Is there a trick to get them assigned, too, in this single step?
Please note, that I don't ask how to export superordinated keywords. I want them in LR to better find photos by category.